# ArangoDB on K8S: thousands of Open FD filedescriptors

Tags: arangodb

On our K8s system we have 4 nodes, where only Arango 3.8.5 services are running

A normal value for "*Open FD*" is **1.60 k**

Sometimes this value is "*exploding*" to over **20.00 k** (= 20000 open file descriptors) and the CPU usage is also very high in this cases

Example Screenshot
[image]

Does anyone has the same issue and know, how we can solve this?